# Find\construct a group of order $q(q-1)$ s.t. .....

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Problem- Let $q$ be a power of a prime $p$ say $q=p^k$. Show that there exists a group $G$ of
order $q(q-1)$ with a normal elementary abelian subgroup of order $q$
and such that all elements of order $p$ in $G$ are conjugate.

I tried it, but failed. let me write here what i thought

$\textbf{Try 1}$ - If i consider $G=(C_p$$\times C_p\times C_p...\times C_p)$$\times C_{q-1}$ where $C_p$'s direct product is $k$ times. Now it is a group of order $q(q-1)$  and also has a normal elementary abelian subgroup of order $q$ but doesn't satisfy all elements of order $p$ in $G$ are conjugate.

May be if I use semidirect products as $G=(C_p$$\times C_p\times C_p...\times C_p)\rtimes_\phi M$ for some group $M$ possibly non abelian of order $q-1$, Is there hope with this, this will need at least an hour of thinking and trying , and choosing a good $\phi$ too?

$\textbf{Try 2}$ - As we know that a minimal normal subgroup of finite solvable group is elementary abelian, so if i can look for a solvable group of order $q(q-1)$ s.t. it has a minimal normal subgroup of order $q$ i am half done, now "elements of order $p$ should be conjugate" is causing trouble. It may be satisfied here, but i am not sure.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your **Try 1** works, but you need to use a semidirect product.

To see how/why, let $C_p\times C_p\times\cdots \times C_p$ be the additive group of the finite field $\Bbb{F}_q$. Also let $C_{q-1}$ be the multiplicative group of the same field (known to be cyclic of order $q-1$). If we let $\Bbb{F}_q^*$ act on $\Bbb{F}_q$ by the field multiplication, then all the non-zero elements of $\Bbb{F}_q$ are in the same orbit of that action. The semidirect product then turns that orbit into a conjugacy class.

---

If you prefer another model (isomorphic to the previous one, but possibly easier to handle), try the group of matrices
$$
G=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{cc}\alpha&\beta\\0&1\end{array}\right)\,\bigg\vert\,\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb{F}_q,\alpha\neq0\right\}.
$$
You may also know this as the group of affine linear transformations of the line $\Bbb{F}_q$.

Comment: yeah , does second approach has any potential?

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth: Can you show that the matrix above has order $p$ if and only if $\alpha=1$ and $\beta\neq0$?

Comment: i will try after some time. i guess i ll be able to. but one thing in first, i dont get that how $\Bbb{F}_q^*$ acts on $C_p\times C_p\times\cdots \times C_p$. how is it additive group of $\Bbb{F}_q$, its additive group is set of elements {$0,1,2,3...q$}

Comment: The additive group of $\Bbb{F}_q$ is a vector space of dimension $k$ over $\Bbb{F}_p$. Have you done much field theory? Do you know what finite fields look like?

Comment: Ok i understand. I have done field theory, just had to look it up again, been a while. yeah $C_p\times C_p\times\cdots \times C_p$ is the additive group of $\Bbb{F}_q$ but if $\Bbb{F}_q^*$ acts on it via field multiplication then you say then all the non-zero elements of $\Bbb{F}_q$ are in the same orbit of that action, that is fine, but i want all elements of order $p$ to be in same orbit, but there will be elements of order $p^2$ , $p^3$ etc in $\Bbb{F}_q$.

Comment: I m sorry I am feeling like I have to completely revise finite fields, but as I guess $\phi$:$\Bbb{F}_q$ $\to$ $Aut(C_p\times C_p\times\cdots \times C_p)$ s.t. $x\in \Bbb{F_q^*}$ goes to $\alpha \in Aut(C_p\times C_p\times\cdots \times C_p)$ s.t. $\alpha(a_1,a_2,...,a_k)=(xa_1,xa_2,...,xa_k)$ is the homomorphism associated to the semidirect product here. Right?

Comment: No, you need to first identify $C_p\times C_p\times \cdots \times C_p\cong\Bbb{F}_p^k$ with $\Bbb{F}_q$. Then you have $\phi:\Bbb{F}_q^*\to Aut(\Bbb{F}_q,+)$ such that $\phi(x)(a)=xa$ for all $x\in\Bbb{F}_q^*$ and all $a\in\Bbb{F}_q$.

Comment: That identification of $\Bbb{F}_q$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{F}_p$ is a lot like identification of complex numbers with vectors $\Bbb{R}^2$, or identification of $\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2)$ with a 3-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{Q}$. Select a basis. In the first case $\{1,i\}$ is a basis of $\Bbb{C}$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$. In the second case a natural basis would be $\{1,\root3\of2,\root3\of4\}$. In the case of finite fields we don't (in general) have such a concrete basis, but one exists. If this was all Greek to you, then you do need to review/learn field extensions.

Comment: Anyway, the group you should end up with is the semidirect product $\Bbb{F}_q\rtimes \Bbb{F}_q^*$. The first component is additive, the second is multiplicative. If you haven't covered finite fields prior to this, then this exercise is a bit cruel. Have you talked about this with your teacher?

Comment: Here's a thought. Can you see how the case $k=1$ works with those matrices? Do that first!

Comment: Ok. now i get it. Thanks alot. because of your this approach, i looked it up many times, and fault was lying in my realization of action of $\Bbb{F}_q^*$ on $\Bbb{F}_q$ as conjugation action under the semidirect product group. now i see why every action, is considered as conjugation inside semi direct product

Comment: Great, Bhaskar! Sorry about not realizing what was holding you back.